# Manga where two students are reincarnated in another world with magic and adventurers

Tags: story-identification, manga

This manga is about two students that died in an accident and are reincarnated in another world with magic and adventurers. The girl can wield magic of like 5 elements. I forgot about the guy, he can also wield magic and was described as "has a lot of potential to grow" or something like that.

- It was a new manga
- I'm sure it's Japanese
- I ran across it online
- I'm sure it was this year, maybe 3 or 4 months ago or maybe longer
- I think genre would be magic/adventure
- It was already translated into English
- I think it was new then when I saw it because it only had like 4 chapters
- I remember the 2 students were mentored by 2 women

Comment: It could be Konosuba although it isn't that new (released as a manga in 2014)

Comment: @Beagon AFAIK, *Konosuba* is about 1 male MC that [*didn't* really die in an accident](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/36414/2516).

Comment: That said, you mentioned "It was already translated into English", is this a licensed translation, or scanlation? This should help narrowing the scope *if* it's a licensed translation, since *isekai* genre has toooooo many titles now....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are refering to [*Isekai Cheat Magician*](https://mangarock.com/manga/mrs-serie-100066043).

[image: Cover of Isekai Cheat Magician]
<sub><sup>*Click to embiggen.*</sup></sub>

The story is about two students who did not die but instead were transported into a world of magic and adventures by a magic circle. As you said in your description, the girl can use multiple elements and the boy, instead of having an elemental affinity can use magic to enhance his body. There is also the 2 women acting as mentors for the students.

[image: Discovery of abilities]
<sub><sup>*Click to embiggen.*</sup></sub>

> And, the boy who has the talent of being a **'Unique Magician'** and isn't aligned with any of the elements.
>
> Fire - wind - earth - water, the girl who has the talent of being a **'Quad Magician'** and is aligned with the four major elements.

The manga itself is fairly recent, with less than a dozen chapter translated into English.